# Find current and previous documents from mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have to return 2 documents from a single query. The first value which I will be giving in the query and the second will be the previous one(sorted).

I am able to design both separately. The below code gives separate outputs.

```
db.collection.find({'_id':'value1'})
db.collection.find({'_id': {'$lt': 'value1'}}).sort({'_id':-1}).limit(1)
```

1. How to combine them? So when I execute from my appl it returns 2 outputs
2. Fetch only a specific key instead of entire document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$lte` instead of `$lt` and limit with `2` - logically it will be the same operation

```
db.collection.find({ _id: { $lte: 'value1' } }, { _id: 1, yourKey: 1 }).sort({_id: -1}).limit(2)
```

EDIT: to get specific keys you need to specify them as second argument of [.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

Comment: Thank you! It works. Anyway I can get a specific key out of this instead of the entire document? I tried [key] at the end but does not work as expected. I only need the 2 values instead of 2 documents

Comment: @BharathKesavan sure, modified my answer